Application Insights: Service Bus dependency in Windows Service application
Application Insights detects Service Bus dependency in .NET ASP (Framework 4.6.2) application. It shows Service Bus as dependency in the Application Map in Azure Portal. But it doesn't work for Windows Service (console). I use the same Application Insights config for the service as for the API and it does not work. Other dependencies are detected perfectly.
How to fix it? Or what diagnostics approach does exist?
ApplicationInsights.config:
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
  <ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
    <Add>core.windows.net</Add>
    <Add>core.chinacloudapi.cn</Add>
    <Add>core.cloudapi.de</Add>
    <Add>core.usgovcloudapi.net</Add>
  </ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
  <IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
    <Add>Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs</Add>
    <Add>Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus</Add>
  </IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
</Add>


So you are trying to trace from Console app ?What is the version of your app ?Please share your .csproj file and code how you configured Application Insights.

We don't have direct option to configure Application Insights from Connected Services as we do in Console (.NET Core App).

I have referred this MSDoc to configure Application Insights manually in .NET Framework Console App.

When you install Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService package ApplicationInsights.config will be created automatically with required packages.

Add the Instrumentation or Connection String in the ApplicationInsights.config file. Change the below properties.




Create a Service Bus Namespace, copy the connection String and create a Queue.

I am able to see the Service Bus Dependency check the below code


My Program.cs file:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AppInsightsConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        private static IQueueClient queClient; 

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

            var telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            telemetryConfiguration.ConnectionString = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.ConnectionString;

            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
                loggingBuilder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Category", LogLevel.Information));

            services.AddSingleton(telemetryConfiguration);
            services.AddSingleton<TelemetryClient>();

            //services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService((ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions options) =>
            //options.ConnectionString = "InstrumentationKey=****");

            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            ILogger<Program> logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

            var tc = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var serviceBusConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://sep27sb.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=nSztLgQP4bY0t4OIFXXKUfP9tCsV90aT8+ASbPevYos=";
            var queueName = "Sample";
            queClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionString, queueName);

            while (true) 
            {               
                using (var op = tc.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("ServiceBus Sample"))
                {
                    var mb = "Hello.. Service Bus";
                    var msg = new Message(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mb));
                    await queClient.SendAsync(msg);

                    logger.LogInformation($"Message sent : {mb} to Service Bus");
                    tc.TrackEvent("Message from Service Bus");
                }
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            await queClient.CloseAsync();
            tc.Flush();
            await Task.Delay(5000); 
        }
    }
}

Application Map:

Dependencies in Transaction Search:

